# ExtJS Charting examples code

Tags: extjs

I am beginner in ExtJs. I am trying to find ExtJS Chart examples only. I have found all the examples but source code doesn't have store defined in that.

Please see the link:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/sandbox/sandbox.html

Actually, I am looking to have all chart examples with complete source code.....

Please provide links for same if you have any.

Thanks,
Raman

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/charts/Bar.html Firebug, Scripts tab, search for store1 (the param being passed in as the store for the examples). Hey presto, the definition of the JSON store being used.

Comment: Thanks a lot Amalea!!  I learned a new thing today!!  it's cool.

Comment: I'll add it as answer then if it helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bar Chart Example](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/charts/Bar.html)

Using Firebug Firefox addon, Scripts tab, search for store1 (the param being passed in as the store for the examples). Hey presto, the definition of the JSON store being used.